# Invalid request error in AWS::Route53::RecordSet when creating stack with AWS CloudFormation json

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Invalid request error in AWS::Route53::RecordSet when creating stack with AWS CloudFormation json. Here is the error:

> CREATE_FAILED AWS::Route53::RecordSet ApiRecordSet    Invalid request

Here is the ApiRecordSet:

```
"ApiRecordSet" : {
      "Type" : "AWS::Route53::RecordSet",
      "Properties" : {
        "AliasTarget" :{
          "DNSName": {"Fn::GetAtt" : ["RestELB", "CanonicalHostedZoneName"]},
          "HostedZoneId": {"Fn::GetAtt": ["RestELB", "CanonicalHostedZoneNameID"]}
        },
        "HostedZoneName" : "some.net.",
        "Comment" : "A records for my frontends.",
        "Name" : {"Fn::Join": ["", ["api",{"Ref": "Env"},".some.net."]]},
        "Type" : "A",
        "TTL" : "300"
      }
    }
```

What is wrong/invalid in this request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing I see immediately wrong is that you are using both an AliasTarget and TTL at the same time. You can't do that since the record uses the TTL defined in the AliasTarget. For more info check out the [documentation on RecordSet here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-route53-recordset.html).

Answer (score 0):

I also got this error and fixed it by removing the "SetIdentifier" field on record sets where it was not needed.

It is only needed when the "Name" and "Type" fields of multiple records are the same.

[Documentation on AWS::Route53::RecordSet](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-route53-recordset.html#cfn-route53-recordset-setidentifier)